# How to sum OVER (PARTITION BY DISTINCT) for Distinct Values

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

I am looking for a clever way of using `Partition by Over` in SQL Server.

I have 3 tables in SQL Server (all `*_id` columns below are just pseudo primary key)

- PO (po_id, po_no);
- PO_ITEM (po_item_id, po_id, po_item_no, qty); // stores ordered quantity for a PO ITEM
- PO_ITEM_DELY (po_item_dely_id, po_item_id, dely_no, dely_qty);   // stores delivered quantity for every item of PO per delivery no.

```
select
    po.po_no, pt.po_item_no, pt.qty, pd.dely_no, pd.dely_qty
from 
    PO
inner join 
    PO_ITEM pt on pt.po_id = po.po_id
inner join 
    PO_ITEM_DELY pd on pd.po_item_id = pt.po_item_id
where 
    po.po_no = 'PO1'
```

Result of this SQL query for reference:

| po_no | po_item_no | qty | dely_no | dely_qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PO1 | PoI11 | 300 | 1 | 210 |
| PO1 | PoI11 | 300 | 2 | 48 |
| PO1 | PoI11 | 300 | 3 | 55 |
| PO1 | PoI12 | 100 | 1 | 100 |
| PO1 | PoI13 | 250 | 1 | 150 |
| PO1 | PoI13 | 250 | 2 | 100 |

So in this example, the Total Ordered Quantity for PO1 is 650, but Total Delivered Qty is 663.

Desired result:

| po_no | OrdPOQty | DelyPOQty | po_item_no | OrdItemQty | delyItemQty | dely_no | dely_qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PO1 | 650 | 663 | PoI11 | 300 | 313 | 1 | 210 |
| PO1 | 650 | 663 | PoI11 | 300 | 313 | 2 | 48 |
| PO1 | 650 | 663 | PoI11 | 300 | 313 | 3 | 55 |
| PO1 | 650 | 663 | PoI12 | 100 | 100 | 1 | 100 |
| PO1 | 650 | 663 | PoI13 | 250 | 250 | 1 | 150 |
| PO1 | 650 | 663 | PoI13 | 250 | 250 | 2 | 100 |

Now I am able to do this task by using subqueries:

```
with poOrdQtyDtl as (
-- Form a Join between PO and PO_ITEM to get Total Ordered Qty Per PO
select
    po.po_id,
    po.po_no,
    sum(pt.qty) OrdPoQty
from PO
inner join PO_ITEM pt on pt.po_id = po.po_id
group by po.po_id, po.po_no
)
select
    poOrdQtyDtl.po_no [PO No.],
    poOrdQtyDtl.OrdPoQty [Ordered Qty For PO],
    sum(itemDely.currDelyQty) over (partition by poOrdQtyDtl.po_no) as [Delivered Qty For Po],
    itemDely.po_item_no [Item No.],
    itemDely.OrdItemQty [Ordred Item Qty],
    itemDely.DelItemQty [Delivered Item Qty],
    itemDely.dely_no [Dely No.],
    itemDely.currDelyQty [Item Qty Delivered in Current Dely]
from poOrdQtyDtl
inner join (
-- Join PO_ITEM and PO_ITEM_DELY to get Item Quantity details
select
    pt.po_id,
    pt.po_item_id,
    pt.po_item_no,
    pt.qty OrdItemQty,
    sum(pd.dely_qty) over (partition by pt.po_item_no) DelItemQty,
    pd.dely_no,
    pd.dely_qty currDelyQty
from PO_ITEM pt
inner join PO_ITEM_DELY pd on pd.po_item_id = pt.po_item_id
) itemDely on itemDely.po_id = poOrdQtyDtl.po_id
WHERE poOrdQtyDtl.po_no = 'PO1'
;
```

However, I was just wondering if there is an easier way of doing sums by more clever application of `over partition by` clause. The main challenge is with the Query below, as I cannot use `distinct` in `partition by` clause.

```
select
    po.po_no,
    -- sum (pt.qty) over (partition by distinct po.po_no, pt.po_item_no) TotPoQOrd, -- INCORRECT
    sum (pt.qty) over (partition by po.po_no, pt.po_item_no) TotPoQOrd,
    sum(pd.dely_qty) over (partition by po.po_no) TotPoQDely,
    pt.po_item_no,
    pt.qty,
    sum(pd.dely_qty) over (partition by po.po_no, pt.po_item_no) TotItemQ,
    pd.dely_no,
    pd.dely_qty
from PO
inner join PO_ITEM pt on pt.po_id = po.po_id
inner join PO_ITEM_DELY pd on pd.po_item_id = pt.po_item_id
where po.po_no = 'PO1'
```

Comment: `PARTITION BY` is basically `GROUP BY`, there is no need to use `DISTINCT` after the `PARTITION BY` clause.

Comment: _"So in this example, the Total Ordered Quantity for PO1 is 650, but Total Delivered Qty is 663."_ - I might be being thick, but where do these numbers come from?

Comment: PO1 has 3 items: PoI11 (Ordered qty = 300), PoI12 (Ordered qty = 100), PoI13 (Ordered qty = 250) So Total of 650. But If add the column of dely_qty in Table 1 then it is 663. Basically PoI11 has been delivered 3 times in delivery no 1, 2, 3. PoI12 delivered only 1 time. PoI13 delivered 2 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use multiple different window specs to solve this one:

```
    select
      x.po_no, 

      x.OrdPOQty,
      SUM(pd.dely_qty) OVER(PARTITION BY x.po_no) as DelyPOQty,
      
      x.po_item_no,

      x.OrdItemQty,
      SUM(pd.dely_qty) OVER(PARTITION BY x.po_no, x.po_item_no) as DelyItemQty,
       
      x.qty, 
      pd.dely_no, 
      pd.dely_qty
    from 
      ( 
        SELECT 
          po.po_id, po.po_no, pt.po_item_id, pt.po_item_no, pt.qty, 
          SUM(pt.qty) OVER(PARTITION BY po.po_no) as OrdPOQty, 
          SUM(pt.qty) OVER(PARTITION BY po.po_no, pt.po_item_no) as OrdItemQty
        FROM PO inner join PO_ITEM pt on pt.po_id = po.po_id
      ) x
      inner join PO_ITEM_DELY pd on pd.po_item_id = x.po_item_id
    where 
      x.po_no = 'PO1'
```

Technically the `partition by po_no` is unnecessary because the where clause ensures there is only one, but i've left it in in case you want to expand the query to consider multiple `po_no`

If you will always only ever query one `po_no`:

```
    select
      x.po_no, 

      x.OrdPOQty,
      SUM(pd.dely_qty) OVER() as DelyPOQty,
      
      x.po_item_no,

      x.OrdItemQty,
      SUM(pd.dely_qty) OVER(PARTITION BY x.po_item_no) as DelyItemQty,
       
      x.qty, 
      pd.dely_no, 
      pd.dely_qty
    from 
      ( 
        SELECT 
          po.po_id, po.po_no, pt.po_item_id, pt.po_item_no, pt.qty, 
          SUM(pt.qty) OVER(PARTITION BY po.po_no) as OrdPOQty, 
          SUM(pt.qty) OVER(PARTITION BY po.po_no, pt.po_item_no) as OrdItemQty
        FROM PO inner join PO_ITEM pt on pt.po_id = po.po_id
      ) x
      inner join PO_ITEM_DELY pd on pd.po_item_id = x.po_item_id
    where 
      x.po_no = 'PO1'
```

> wondering if there is an easier way of doing sums by more clever application of over partition by clause

Well, essentially with the basic form you end up with N repeats of a row, and you could count the repeats and divide the sum of the values in the group by the number of repeats of the group, so you're summing values that are a third of their original but repeated 3 times for the same overall sum.. But I do feel it makes a bigger mess than just doing the summing and counting at the level where there is no cartesian product, and then that result just gets carried out and repeated..

Or we could count only one of the items, presuming that every item will at least have an delivery #1:

```
select
  po.po_no, 

  SUM(CASE WHEN pd.dely_no = 1 THEN pt.qty ELSE 0 END) OVER(PARTITION BY po.po_no) as OrdPOQty,
  SUM(pd.dely_qty) OVER(PARTITION BY po.po_no) as DelyPOQty,
  
  pt.po_item_no,

  SUM(CASE WHEN pd.dely_no = 1 THEN pt.qty ELSE 0 END) OVER(PARTITION BY po.po_no, pt.po_item_no) as OrdItemQty,
  SUM(pd.dely_qty) OVER(PARTITION BY po.po_no, pt.po_item_no) as DelyItemQty,
   
  pt.qty, 
  pd.dely_no, 
  pd.dely_qty
from 
  PO
  inner join PO_ITEM pt on pt.po_id = po.po_id
  inner join PO_ITEM_DELY pd on pd.po_item_id = pt.po_item_id
where 
  po.po_no = 'PO1'
```

If you add another table that causes the `pd.dely_no` to have repeats of value 1 per `po/po+item` partitions then you'll need to extend the CASE logic

Comment: I am using po_no = 'PO1' in where clause only to limit the result to show PO1 as an example. Actually, I would want to expand it to produce this for all POs. However, the SQL proposed will not produce correct results. I have edited the SQL to show which columns will produce incorrect results. The issue is that if an item is having multiple deliveries, then that row repeats. For e.g. PoI11 has ordered a quantity of 300, but it was delivered 3 times with delivered qty = 210 + 48 + 55 = 313. This will cause the row PO_ITEM.qty to repeat and therefore will wrongly added 3 times.

Comment: Edited so that the summing of orders is done before the joining in of delivery, which is what I understand to be the thing causing the po/item rows to repeat

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have accepted this answer because it does solve the problem. I did however know that I could solve this problem using subqueries as noted in the original post.

Comment: As noted at the end of the answer, youre effectively asking "how can I solve at the outer layer this problem I *caused* by not doing something earlier" - You have one PO,and 3 items - that's nice and easy to sum up per PO but keep the detail, using SUM()OVER().. But then you join those items (unique) into deliveries and they become not-unique - so you've caused the database to have to repeat them. By looking for a way to remove them again after you've caused the repeat, the database has to do more work to remove data that was introduced.

Comment: This can of course be done, but it's a bit like walking through mud and into the house, then wondering the best way to clean the house - taking shoes off earlier would mean there isn't any post processing work to do cleaning the mud up, and it's easier. There are plenty of ways to dress this up - using a WITH or baking the SUM OVER  into a view and then querying on the view joined with the delivery table for example

Comment: I did, however, add another note/suggestion at the end of the answer. If you find any typos, just correct the typos - the code doesn't need a supplementary comment of what was fixed